# MVC Dropdown in partialview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I designed a web site with MVC3 technology. 
i have a main view and partial view. in partial view i have dropdownlist that shows name of cities and partial view is in main view. i want when user select a city (from partial view) and then submit click(in main view) get and save selected value in database.

**partial view** 
i have viewmodel that has selectid for selected value.
    @html.dropdownlist("selectid",new SelectList(Model.Lcitylist, "Value", "Text"))

**how i can get selected value from partial view?
please help me**
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post action should have an argument called `selectid`, it will contain you selected value. It works the same if your drop down list is in your main view or in a partial view, as it is based on the name you give to you drop down list.